# How to do in PHP that when everytime the page is loaded, variable $emailError will be false

Tags: php, html

How to do in PHP that everytime that the page is re-loaded, the variable $emailError will defaultly be set to false?
i wanna do it for a log in system.

i thought, maybe sessions would work.
here's my code for now.

```
<?php
include 'dbconnection.php';
$emailError = false;
if (isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if (empty($email)||!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailError = true;
    } else {
    $emailError = false;
}}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up / SociaLane</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="signup.css">
    <link rel="Icon" href="logos/circlelogo.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    <?php
    if ($emailError == true) {
        echo
        "#email {
        border-color: #ff0000;
        }";   
    } else {
        echo
        "#email {
        border-color: black;
        }";   
    };
    ?>
    </style>
 </head>
```

Comment: `$emailError = false;`

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, but that defines it. i want to do that even if it was true, when ill refresh it would become false.

Comment: Do you mean - everytime the page is **re-loaded** ?? (not everytime the page is loaded)

Comment: @KenLee Yes, sorry and thank you

Comment: `i want to do that even if it was true, when ill refresh it would become false`...that's already how web applications work - they are stateless. If the script is re-loaded, it starts again from the beginning, with no memory of what happened last time it was executed. So it doesn't matter what value you had set the variable to previously, it will start again as `false`, if you put `$emailError = false;` as the first line of the code. Have you found a situation where you think that is not the behaviour you are seeing? If so please provide a [mre] of that issue, so we can help you to fix it.

Comment: @ADyson just added my code. thanks

Comment: Ok thanks. And what exactly is the problem you're having, though? As far as I can see, each time you load this script, `$emailError = false;` will set that variable to false. It can only be set true if a form is submitted and a specific field is empty.

Comment: when i refresh the border dosent change to black. (tried to clear cache) here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkscyTBI0_A sorry for the poor quality and thanks for all the help!

Comment: If you use the "reload" button in your browser directly after submitting a form, it will submit that form again. This is standard browser behaviour, and is not a problem with php. Your browser should have given you a warning that it was going to do that - unless you have chosen to turn such warnings off, of course. Also...did you not do any basic debugging in your code, to check the values of variables and show which path your code was taking?? This would have revealed to you that the POST data was being sent again.

Comment: To avoid such an issue, don't use the refresh button, instead load the page again from the URL bar.

Comment: @ADyson Wow, sorry for the ignorance. im kinda new to php. thank you very much for all of you help today!

Answer (score 1):

For your code, if the user reloads the page, the browser will prompt a warning to the user asking whether he/she would like to "re-submit" the form, and so the $emailError will always be true (if he/she answers yes to the warning).

In that case, you may use a session variable (say $_SESSION["submitcount"])  to detect whether the form has been submitted:

1. initalize the session variable as 0 if it does not exist
2. if $emailError is set to true as in your if-condition, increment the session variable by 1
3. amend your if-conditiion so that **only if** the session variable is 0, the $emailError will be set to true

So the code will be:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'dbconnection.php';

if (! isset($_SESSION["submitcount"])){$_SESSION["submitcount"]=0;}

$emailError = false;

if (isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if ((empty($email)||!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && $_SESSION["submitcount"]==0)  {


        $emailError = true;
        
        $_SESSION["submitcount"]++;

    } else {
    $emailError = false;
}}
?>
 
// Other code ....
```